# Error setting up a google cloud platform server

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, google-cloud-platform

After running this command,
this is the error I am getting. How do I fix this please.

`ssh: connect to host 35.230.96.246 port 22: Connection timed out`

> Recommendation: To check for possible causes of SSH connectivity
> issues and get recommendations, rerun the ssh command with the
> --troubleshoot option.

`gcloud compute ssh lab-1 --project=utopian-eye-406408 --zone=us-west1-b --troubleshoot`

Or, to investigate an IAP tunneling issue:

`gcloud compute ssh lab-1 --project=utopian-eye-406408 --zone=us-west1-b --troubleshoot --tunnel-through-iap`

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code
> [255].

I tried running this command to enable ssh;
`gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-ssh`

An this this command too;
`gcloud compute ssh lab-1 --project=utopian-eye-406408 --zone=us-west1-b --troubleshoot --tunnel-through-iap`

Comment: Can you run `telnet 35.230.96.246 22` from the machine you are trying to ssh from? Check `nsg` logs & could be that `35.230.96.246` has local `firewalld`/`ufw` daemons running blocking the ingress SSH traffic

Comment: Connection timeout means nobody is listening for connections on that port or a firewall is blocking connections or you specified the wrong IP address. Is the VM running and is OpenSSH running on that server? Don't guess - validate as some tiny instances fail to correctly startup. Does the VM OS have a firewall configured? Do you have a VPC ingress firewall rule allowing port 22?